# Custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer doesn't resolve embedded property values

Tags: java, spring, property-placeholder

I have a Spring 4.3 custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that does extra processing on values read from the properties files before injection:

```java
public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{ 

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(final String originalValue) { ... }

    @Override
    protected String resolveSystemProperty(final String key) {
       return convertPropertyValue(super.resolveSystemProperty(key));
    }
}
```

My problem is that bean fields that are annotated for injection with property values, eg. `@Value("${some_property}")`, are in fact injected with the raw value read from the property source without my custom processing.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found that I should have also overiden `com.ec.survey.security.SafePasswordPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#resolvePlaceholder`